# Python. Выводит none, при попытке сортировки двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=(2, 3))
n = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
m = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])

print(n, "\n", type(n))
print()
print(m, "\n", type(m))
print()
print(n.sort(axis=1))
```

Для себя создал несколько двумерных массивов, чтобы проверить на каждом сортировку через axis=1, axis=2. Во всех случаях выводило 'None'. Так же хочу спросить что значит приставка после np - '.array', всё равно все массивы имеют тип 'numpy.ndarray', даже массив 'a', в котором не было данной приставки, так какой смысл тогда от неё.

Answer (score 1):

1. Функция `sort()` [ВСЕГДА возвращает `None`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/list.sort/), однако при этом она таки сортирует массив *на месте*. Достаточно лишь вызвать данную функцию, а затем вывести массив.

```py
...
n.sort(axis=0)
print(n)

# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [7 8 9]]
```

2. Опять же, [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) — это *функция*, образующая массив данных вида *`nparray`* — основной тип данных массива в NumPy. Данная функция — просто один из способов создания объекта подобного типа, другой метод — генерация numpy-массивов на примере массива `a` с использованием других numpy-функций.